# How can I call a script in .profile?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, .profile

I have an alias in .profile that clears the terminal when "c" is entered:

```
alias c='clear'
```

I want to call a KornShell (ksh) script every time I enter "c" in the terminal. What is the best way to accomplish this? I have googled and not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias is essentially just a text replacement for what you actually type. Try modifying your alias to read

```
alias c='clear; myscript.ksh'
```